# How do i know that google apis are available?

Tags: google-maps, recaptcha

I have a site where i am using Google Map API v2 and google ReCAPTCHA. How do i know that those apis are online. I mean to say that google api site is down on not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Google Maps goes, there's this from 2006:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/5d36a96bf74af924

Set up the testing object which will be overwritten by the API if it's available.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var google;
function isFunction(a) { return typeof a == "Function" }
function isObject(a) { return (a && typeof a == "Object") || isFunction(a) }
</script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file..."></script>
```

Then wrap your map script in a test:

```
<script>
if (isObject(google)) { ... }
</script>
```

All Google APIs use the `google` namespace so this should work across the board. But you can substitute `google` with a typical base object to test for a specific API (eg `GMap2`), as shown in the original forum thread.

Note that there are other pitfalls like the tileservers being down, or the user himself blocking images from Google, which this won't help with. The original discussion is worth reading.